# Rascal MPL dynamically get properties / fields of variable

Tags: reflection, properties, rascal

I often find myself testing using [typeOf](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/library/type/#Type-typeOf) whenever I'm lost. Is there a similar way to print all properties or fields of a variable, similar to [Object.keys (JavaScript)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [vars (Python)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print all the *current* keyword fields of a constructor:

```
import Node;
iprintln(getKeywordParameters(myInput));
```

I use that a lot to print the fields of an M3 model, for example. However, that does not print the fields that have *not* been set. Rascal is a statically typed language, and there is information which can be retrieved which is not present in the value (default fields for example).

If I want to know the general signature of a function or constructor, I type the name in the console, then click on its source location:

```
rascal>println
value: choice(
  [
    function(|file:///Users/jurgenv/git/rascal/src/org/rascalmpl/library/IO.rsc|(11118,784,<418,0>,<455,36>)),
    function(|file:///Users/jurgenv/git/rascal/src/org/rascalmpl/library/IO.rsc|(11904,69,<457,0>,<458,27>))
  ],
  [])
```

That works for constructors are well, so you can see which positional fields they have or keyword fields.

To find out the name of the current constructor:

```
import Node;
getName(myValue);
```

Comment: So the `M3` type is also a `Node` I see. `list[Declaration]` is not.

Comment: When I type `println` into the console I get `Undeclared variable: println`, even though I can execute my Rascal program!

Comment: Yes; we run the code in an interpreter until it fails even though we also have a typechecker. Sometimes comes in handy, sometimes it's confusing.